# Регулярное выражение работает не правильно

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть простая строка типа `Улица Пушкина 124 (доп. текст) (Район)`

1. Первое слово обозначает тип(Улица, Проспект, Дорога и т.д).
2. Дальше идет само название улицы и дополнительный текст.
3. И третий элемент это район города.

Я написал простенькую регулярку на `PHP`, `/^([А-я]+)(.*)\(([А-я]+)\)$/`
и она по суте работает на сайте regex101.com, но когда я хочу использовать это выражения в проекте то в лучшем случае получаю:

```
   Array
   (
       [0] => Улица Пушкина 124 (доп. текст) (Район)
       [1] => Ули�
       [2] => �а Пушкина 124 (доп. текст) 
       [3] => Район
   )
```

а в худшем вообще ничего.
Посмотреть можно здесь [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/jDeSX9/1)
Возможно ли что у меня PHP не той версии(5.6) или не правильно настроен? Или какие варианты могут быть?

Comment: 1. Модификатор `u` для UTF-8 требуется. 2. `А-я` захватывает не только буквы русского алфавита и не все из них!

Comment: @Visman спасибо, первый вариант подошел

Comment: См. также: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453907/213987

Comment: Буквы лучше хватать так - [А-Яа-яЁё]

Comment: @AlexeyShatrov проще i поставить

Comment: @Arendach, правильно делать `[а-яё]` и дописывать модификатор `i`.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [preg\_match некорректно обрабатывает кириллицу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/263332/preg-match-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83)