# PHP | preg_match_all выдает по буквам

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярка:

> /[\p{L}-—]+(?:\h[\p{L}-—]+)*(?=,)?/m

Проверена на сайте: https://regex101.com/r/ojQ1Hy/3

Проблема в том, что Laravel, а точнее php, выдает мне ответ **по буквам**, хотя на сайте выдает **по словам**. Что я делаю не так?

```
$re = '/[\p{L}-—]+(?:\h[\p{L}-—]+)*(?=,)?/m';
$str = 'гендерная интрига, драма, история, комедия, повседневность, приключения, психология, романтика, сёнэн-ай, яой';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
var_dump($matches);
```

Результат:

```
[0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "�"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "е�"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "�"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "ер�"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "�"
  }
  ...
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [preg\_match некорректно обрабатывает кириллицу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/263332/preg-match-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83)

Comment: Нет, вопрос не в кодировки, а в том, что регулярка неправильно работала.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Проблема была в регулярном выражении:

> /[(pL-—)]+(?:\h[(pL-—)]+)*(?=,)?/m

Вместо:

> /[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ-—]+(?:\h[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ-—]+)*(?=,)?/mu <- и добавить модификатор **u**, чтобы кодировка была многобайтовой