# Разбиение строки по заглавному символу php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

помогите составить правильно регулярку. Нужна обработка строки как латиницей так и кириллицей, как обьединить [A-Z][^A-Z] и [А-Я][^А-Я]?

```
$fio = 'YusifovaVusale';
$res = array();
preg_match_all('/[A-Z][^A-Z]*/',$fio,$res,PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r ($res);

$fio = 'ЮзифоваВусаля';
$res = array();
preg_match_all('/[А-Я][^А-Я]*/',$fio,$res,PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r ($res);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто объединить

```php
preg_match_all('/[А-ЯA-Z][^А-ЯA-Z]*/',$fio,$res,PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Comment: Вроде не будет работать...

Comment: @Qwertiy почему?

Comment: https://ideone.com/enm9pq

Answer (score 2):

Используйте `preg_split`:

```php
$fio = 'YusifovaVusaleЮзифоваВусаля';
print_r( preg_split('~(?!^)(?=\p{Lu})~u', $fio) );
// -> Array
// (
//     [0] => Yusifova
//     [1] => Vusale
//     [2] => Юзифова
//     [3] => Вусаля
// )
```

См. [пример работы кода](https://3v4l.org/fI39N).

**Подробности**:

- `(?!^)` - блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, запрещающий совпадение в начале строки
- `(?=\p{Lu})` - блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, требующий наличия заглавной буквы справа.

Модификатор `u` [обязателен](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/263332/).

Answer (score 0):

Для мультибайтных строк нужно поставить модификатор `u`в конце http://phpweb.hostnet.com.br/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php:

```
$fio = 'ЮзифоваВусаля';
$res = array();
preg_match_all('/[А-Я][^А-Я]*/u',$fio,$res,PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r ($res);
```

Comment: Что там насчёт `ё`?

Comment: @Qwertiy про "ё" никто не спрашивал ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Я конечно могу дописать её, но если автор не написал - то я считаю, что ему (ей) это не нужно)) А заглядывать в голову автору не хочу)

Comment: М.б. надёжнее использовать символьные классы? `\p{Cyrillic}` и `\p{Latin}`?

Comment: @Эдуард увы о таких не знаю. Если вы знаете - напишите ответ)

Comment: просили объединить кириллицу и латиницу, а тут для латиницы не срабатывает